# RSS pubDate not getting displayed

Tags: asp.net, .net, rss

I have an xml file live below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
  <title>About RSS</title>
  <link>http://localhost:27549/TTTT.aspx</link>
  <description>The latest news</description>
  <image><url>http://localhost:27549/images/ttt_logo.jpg</url></image>
  <item>
    <title>ABC</title>
    <link>http://localhost:27549/Viewttt.aspx?id=217</link>
    <description>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...</description>
    <pubDate>Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM</pubDate>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Though you can see the pubdate tag, it wont get displayed in the pubDate position. This is my code in getting pubdate which does not work,

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
pubDate = dt.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:sstt");


writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", pubDate);
```

For exmaple I tried getting todays date like below,

```
writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
```

and the date is getting displayed.
What might be wrong in the 1st set of code ?

```
String pubDate = "";

            using (System.Data.Common.DbCommand dbCommand = DataAccess.Instance().Database.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_GetLatestNews"))
            {

                using (IDataReader reader = DataAccess.Instance().Database.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            newsHeader = "New News Summary Available for " + reader["Title"].ToString() + " - " + reader["PubDate"];
                            newsLink = "ViewTTT.aspx?id=" + reader["Id"].ToString();
                            newsDesc = reader["FullDescription"].ToString();
                            pubDate = reader["pubDate"].ToString();
                            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                            pubDate = dt.ToString("r");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                };

            }

AddRSSItem(writer, newsHeader, newsUrl, newsDesc, pubDate);
.............
.............

public XmlTextWriter AddRSSItem(XmlTextWriter writer,
                 string sItemTitle, string sItemLink,
                 string sItemDescription, String pubDate)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");
            writer.WriteElementString("title", sItemTitle);
            writer.WriteElementString("link", sItemLink);
            writer.WriteElementString("description", sItemDescription);
            writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", pubDate);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            return writer;
        }
```

Comment: So, is the date getting displayed or isn't getting displayed?

Comment: I have updated my question, my 1st set of code in getting pubDate wldnt work.

Comment: So, in the first line of your code: `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, ....)`, what is in the `pubDate` variable at that point, and should you be using the `MM/dd/yyyy` format specifier?

Comment: pubDate is '08/30/2011' and yes format should be MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Last question:  In your example that doesn't work, does pubDate have a value _(Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM)_ just before you call `writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", pubDate)` ?

Comment: Yes my debug shows pubDate -Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM" and my view source also shows the same. However its not getting dispalyed in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you go with the format that you have stated works:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
pubDate = dt.ToString("r");
writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", pubDate);
```

Observe that I'm using the `"r"` specifier *Tue, 30 Aug 2011 00:00:00 GMT* as opposed to `"dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:sstt"` *Tuesday, August 30, 2011, 00:00:00AM* which are different formats.

Comment: I tried the same as above, but im getting Monday, August 29, 2011 8:00 PM not the exact date/day....

Comment: The key is to use the "r" pattern.  You can't get _Monday, August 29, 2011 8:00 PM_ if you are using the "r" (RFC1123) pattern.  You should be seeing _Mon, 29 Aug 2011 xx:xx:xx GMT_.

Comment: DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            
                            pubDate = dt.ToString("r");writer.WriteElementString("pubDate", pubDate); this gives me "Monday, August 29, 2011 8:00 PM"

Comment: Supply all the code that generates the xml.  You must be leaving out some relevant code.  Somewhere you must be overwriting it.